# autoconf check for missing prototype

Tags: autoconf

Is there a better way to write an autoconf test for a missing prototype than by setting CFLAGS to "-Werror -Wimplicit-function-declaration" ?

Specifically, I'm trying to determine if I need to provide my own `pwrite(2)`
and `pread(2)`.  If the environment is strict, pread/pwrite are not defined.
here's what I have now, which works:

```
AC_INIT([pwrite],[0.0.0],[none],[nothing],[nowhere])

AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
old_CFLAGS=$CFLAGS
CFLAGS="-Werror $CFLAGS"

AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM(,[
    #ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
    #include <unistd.h>
    #endif

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int ret = pwrite(99, "blah", 1, 0);
        return 0;
    } ]) ],
    AC_MSG_RESULT([using system pwrite prototype])
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_PWRITE, 1, [pwrite protoype exists]),
    AC_MSG_RESULT([no pwrite protoype. using our own])
    )

CFLAGS=$old_CFLAGS

AC_OUTPUT()
```

When I do this, `configure CFLAGS=-std=c99` will indeed detect that pwrite is declared implicitly, and `configure` alone will find a pwrite prototype in unistd.h.   However, mucking with CFLAGS inside configure doesn't seem like the "autoconf-y" way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving/restoring CFLAGS is acceptable but for this particular purpose, `AC_CHECK_DECLS` turns out to be precisely what I was looking for, and furthermore does not have any problems with super-picky compilers or trying to figure out what is the Portland Group compiler equivalent to -Werror-implicit-function-declaration.

```
AC_INIT([pwrite],[0.0.0],[none],[nothing],[nowhere])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([unistd.h])
AC_CHECK_DECLS([pwrite])
AC_OUTPUT()
```

and then in my code I do have to check the result a little differently:

```
#if (HAVE_DECL_PWRITE == 0)
... implement our own pwrite 
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source of the autoconf macros you find that a lot of them save and restore CFLAGS. You need to be very careful using `-Werror` though, as you might get incorrect results. e.g., if `argc`, `argv` are unused - as is `ret` - a warning (see: `-Wunused*` flags) will be interpreted as `pwrite` being unavailable.

Assuming `<unistd.h>` compiles without warning-as-errors, which it should:

```
<save CFLAGS>
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Werror=implicit-function-declaration"

AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
  [[#ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
    #include <unistd.h>
    #endif]],
  [[(void) pwrite(99, "blah", 1, 0);]])],
  <action-on-success>,
  <action-on-fail>)

<restore CFLAGS>
```

The `(void)` cast is probably unnecessary - it's for crazy-strict warnings that will probably not be silent even for system headers, but doesn't hurt. It might be worth looking at the [`_XOPEN_SOURCE`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros) macro value - e.g., setting `_XOPEN_SOURCE` in this test and the library code.